# Count the Occurence of word,Total words and total Unique words in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse, tidytext

I have a huge `df` which has a `doc_id` and `word`, and every `word` can contain multiple `class(Class_1,Class_2,Class_3 )` so if a word is in that `class` i put `1` there or if not then `0`

**SAMPLE DF**

```
doc_id   word       Class_1   Class_2   Class_3 
104      saturn       1         0         1
104      survival     1         1         0
104      saturn       1         0         1
104      car          0         1         0  
118      baseball     1         1         0
118      color        0         0         1
118      muscle       0         1         0
187      image        1         0         0
187      pulled       0         0         0
187      game         1         0         1
187      play         0         0         1 
187      game         1         1         0 
125      translation  1         0         0  
125      survival     0         1         0
125      input        1         0         1      
125      excellent    1         0         0 
142      nice         0         1         0
142      article      0         1         0 
142      original     1         0         1
142      content      0         1         0
```

Now using this `sample DF` i want to `count` number of Occurrences of `word` in `class(Class_1,Class_2,Class_3)`.
Total words in each `class(Class_1,Class_2,Class_3)`, `eg:` like how many `words` are there in `Class_1`
and lastly total `unique words` in all documents.

**OUTPUT DF** should be something like this

```
doc_id   word       Occ_1  Occ_2  Occ_3  Totl_1  Totl_2  Totl_3  Unique_words 
104      saturn       2      0      2      11     9       7       17
104      survival     1      2      0      11     9       7       17
104      car          0      1      0      11     9       7       17
118      baseball     1      1      0      11     9       7       17
118      color        0      0      1      11     9       7       17
118      muscle       0      1      0      11     9       7       17
187      image        1      0      0      11     9       7       17
187      pulled       0      0      0      11     9       7       17  
187      game         2      1      1      11     9       7       17
187      play         0      0      1      11     9       7       17
125      translation  1      0      0      11     9       7       17 
125      input        1      0      1      11     9       7       17
125      excellent    1      0      0      11     9       7       17
142      nice         0      1      0      11     9       7       17
142      article      0      1      0      11     9       7       17 
142      original     1      0      1      11     9       7       17
142      content      0      1      0      11     9       7       17
```

**Whereas**
`Occ_1` = Number of Occurrences of Word in `Class_1` and same for other `Class_2`and `Class_3`
`Totl_1` = Total Words in `Class_1` and same for other `Class_2`and `Class_3`
`Unique_words` = Number of Total Unique Words in All Documents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, you can run the following lines:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(word) %>%
  summarise(
    doc_id = first(doc_id),
    Occ_1 = sum(Class_1),
    Occ_2 = sum(Class_2),
    Occ_3 = sum(Class_3)
  ) %>%
  arrange(doc_id, word) %>%
  mutate(
    Totl_1 = sum(Occ_1),
    Totl_2 = sum(Occ_2),
    Totl_3 = sum(Occ_3),
    Unique_words = n()
  )
```

**Output**

```
   word        doc_id Occ_1 Occ_2 Occ_3 Totl_1 Totl_2 Totl_3 Unique_words
   <chr>       <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>        <int>
 1 car         104        0     1     0     11      9      7           17
 2 saturn      104        2     0     2     11      9      7           17
 3 survival    104        1     2     0     11      9      7           17
 4 baseball    118        1     1     0     11      9      7           17
 5 color       118        0     0     1     11      9      7           17
 6 muscle      118        0     1     0     11      9      7           17
 7 excellent   125        1     0     0     11      9      7           17
 8 input       125        1     0     1     11      9      7           17
 9 translation 125        1     0     0     11      9      7           17
10 article     142        0     1     0     11      9      7           17
11 content     142        0     1     0     11      9      7           17
12 nice        142        0     1     0     11      9      7           17
13 original    142        1     0     1     11      9      7           17
14 game        187        2     1     1     11      9      7           17
15 image       187        1     0     0     11      9      7           17
16 play        187        0     0     1     11      9      7           17
17 pulled      187        0     0     0     11      9      7           17
```

I have added an `arrange` function in order to sort your dataset by `doc_id` and `word`, otherwise the output dataset would have been sorted alphabetically by `word`.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to figure out another solution

Comment: @jamesjoyce I've added a couple of lines in the code, now it should work as you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

### Install these packages:

```
necessary_packages <-
  c("dplyr", "tiydr")
new_packages <-
  necessary_packages[!(necessary_packages %in% installed.packages()[, "Package"])]
if (length(new_packages) > 0) {
  install.packages(new_packages, dependencies = TRUE)
}
lapply(necessary_packages, require, character.only = TRUE)
```

### Now lets count the words and reshape your df:

```
df <- 
df %>%
gather("class", "n", 3:6) %>%
group_by(word, class) %>%
mutate(occ = sum(n)) %>%
ungroup() %>%
group_by(class) %>%
mutate(class_totl = sum(n)) %>%
ungroup() %>% 
mutate(Unique_words = sum(n)) %>%
select(doc_id, word, occ, class_total, Unique_words) %>%
gather(variable, value, 3:6) %>%
spread(variable, value)
```

## Note: I haven't run the above code, because you didn't provide code to build your df.

Comment: Error in inds_combine(.vars, ind_list) : Position must be between 0 and n

Comment: ##replace the line; gather(variable, value, 3:6) %>% 
TO 
gather(variable, value, 3:5) %>%

Comment: still not working..Thanks for your time..@Ric S has been marked